# Can RHEL6 VM Guest access some files of RHEL6 Server, Host

Tags: networking, virtualization, redhat

Can the guest vm's access the host machine file system in RHEL6 virtualization?
Is there any protocol? And how to configure it? Because the guests should have access to host files every time and without doing the configuration every time.

Excuse me, if my question is not with proper n/w terminologies, because I am new to N/W concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upvoted Beerey. Just also wanted to say that the most common way to achieve what you're after is by using NFS and automount or even have the NFS mount in fstab.

Comment: Exectly this is what my boss wants.Bcos he wants to avoid ssh.So dyasny, this will work out for me.

Comment: Got another Query,i think you can answer this as well.If i clone a guest VM does it use the same Hard disk space of the guest.

Comment: if you clone a guest VM, it will create a new virtual disk image. this image will take up space, depending on the clone parameters and the original disk size. if you use preallocated v-disks, then yes, all sizes will be the same, with sparse, there's more to take into account

Answer (score 2):

Guest VMs are isolated from the host under KVM - from within the VM you are not able to access the filesystem or the host resources through any method not available to a normal machine.

However, they are able to access the hosts via the network (ssh/ftp/http/etc), in the same way that a separate, physical machine is.  This holds true unless you have configured the network to block access to the host or turned off those access methods.

Generally, a standard RHEL6/RHEV host will have at least SSH enabled, and guest VMs aren't VLANed or otherwise segregated automatically.  You should therefore be able to access the host and its files via SSH.

Comment: You explained to me all the aspects, and i really thank you.

Comment: i wanted to upvote this but i dont have enough reputation.